# How to install scikit-image with OSGeo4W on WIndows 10

Tags: python, qgis, scikit-image

I'm trying to install scikit-image through OSGeo4W shell on Windows 10 but the only result I got are alot of errors.
http://pastebin.com/rPjAr96T

I have install scikit-image on my standart python istallation but I need it for a QGis plugin which I made.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to install with a wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.